# Xamarin in Visual Studio 2017 - Installing the NDK and HAXM

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin.forms, android-ndk, haxm

I've set up Xamarin in VS through the Visual Studio Installer. I selected the `Android NDK` `13b` and also selected the `Intel HAXM`.

Problem is:

> 1) The NDK does not show up under any selection.
>
> 2) Android device manager keeps stating that HAXM is not installed.

I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling them and even restarting my system, but it still isn't working. As a result, I keep getting errors when I try to run the `Android Device Manager` or launch the `emulator`.

If anyone has any suggestions, please let me know. I'm half a mind do to a total reinstall

Comment: Did you have an Intel or AMD micro? Also did you try downloading the ndk manually?

Comment: Nope, no micro. I didn't try installing the `NDK` manually though. I'm mainly perplexed by it because both installed fine on my other computer.

Comment: I asked you about your micro because HAXM only runs on Intel.

Can you provide the exact error you're receiving @brake ?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. Yes, I run on Intel. Regarding the `NDK` problem, there is no error output. After installing it through the Visual Studio Installer, I checked my folders but could not find any sort of NDK-related folder. Regarding the HAXM problem, if I try to open a device in the Android Device Manager it displays a pop-up stating that I need to install HAXM, even though I just used the VS Installer to do just that.